# Create Batch file to run mstest for coded ui test automation

Tags: batch-file

Can someone help me out in creating Batch file to run the coded ui test using mstest?

I am currently running the coded ui test in the command prompt by running as administrator by using below lines in command prompt:

```
cd\
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest.exe /testcontainer:D:\Working\LOPS_Testing\LOPS6Automation\bin\LOPS6Automation.dll /test:Light_Oil_Price_System.Scripts.PricingScreen_Script.PricingScreenFunctionality
```

This works correctly.

But now I want to use the same in a batch file. Can some one help me out to create a batch file by using the above code?

Comment: Try to copy that code into an empty file. Then rename to something.bat. Then you can execute it with double click.

Comment: As you suggested, I have given below in .bat file:

Comment: @echo off
cd\ cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest.exe /testcontainer:D:\Working\LOPS_Testing\LOPS6Automation\bin\LOPS6Automation.dll /test:Light_Oil_Price_System.Scripts.PricingScreen_Script.PricingScreenFunctionality
pause

Comment: But it is giving below error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If the paths have spaces, wrap the path between quotes "C:\Program Files\..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap paths with spaces between quotes.

I also used `cd /D`, that changes drive if necessary (for example if you were on drive D: you would need to change to C: before `cd` commands. With `/D` option this is done automatically)

Also, since you are already on the `Common7\IDE` folder, you don't need to write again the directory, you could just call MSTest.exe:

```
cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

MSTest.exe /testcontainer:D:\Working\LOPS_Testing\LOPS6Automation\bin\LOPS6Automation.dll /test:Light_Oil_Price_System.Scripts.PricingScreen_Script.PricingScreenFunctionality
```

Comment: As I understand it, `MSTest` does not use its own directory, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` as the working directory, and since all paths have been provided by the OP, I see no reason to change directory at all. That said a single command/line should do it: `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"D:\Working\LOPS_Testing\LOPS6Automation\bin\LOPS6Automation.dll" /test:Light_Oil_Price_System.Scripts.PricingScreen_Script.PricingScreenFunctionality`

Comment: True, but since I was not 100% sure if the current work directory would be used or not, I prefered to CD to the directory. He may also do several calls to other executables on same directory. It just sounded like the safest bet :-)